# Get all the positive values of $n$ such that $10^{n+3} + 20^n + 5$ has remainder $2$ when is divided by $3$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

By the definition of division I have that

$$10^{n+3} + 20^n + 5 = 3q + 2$$

but now I have two variables (**n** and **q**) that I have to solve and no more extra information. What be the approach I should take?

Thanks

Comment: Finding $q$ is irrelevant. We just need to know that it is an integer. In fact, the task is "Find all $n$ that makes $q$ an integer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $10\equiv1\pmod3$ and $20\equiv-1\pmod3$, $10^{n+3}+20^n+5\equiv(-1)^n\pmod3$. So, the answer is: when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you! that solves it.